# ORDER BY and LIMIT are not working while using UNION

Tags: mysql, sql, database, union

This is my query:

```
mysql_query("SELECT userid FROM messages WHERE userid<>'$myid' AND friendid='$myid' AND status=1 UNION SELECT friendid FROM messages WHERE userid='$myid' AND friendid<>'$myid' AND status=1");
```

I want to add paging so I need to limit the number of friends I message. But whenever I add LIMIT it shows error. Also I want to show newest messages first `ORDER BY time DESC` but that doesn't also work. Help ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enclose that query inside a subquery and `ORDER BY ... LIMIT...` in the outer one:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT userid 
    FROM messages 
    WHERE userid   <> '$myid' 
      AND friendid = '$myid' 
      AND status = 1 
    UNION 
    SELECT friendid 
    FROM messages
    WHERE userid = '$myid' 
      AND friendid <> '$myid' 
      AND status = 1
) AS sub
ORDER BY ...
LIMIT ...;
```

Comment: everything is fine except that it shows: unknown column time in order clause. I tried `ORDER BY time DESC` and `ORDER BY sub.time DESC` too!

Comment: @Adil - There is no selected column with the name `time`, add it in the subquery: `SELECT * FROM ( SELECT userid, time FROM ... UNION SELECT friendid, time from ...) AS sub ...`

Answer (score 1):

Try maybe

```
SELECT DISTINCT userid FROM...
```